# Does anyone know where the Google App Engine local datastore file located for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, local-storage

Does anyone know where the Google App Engine local datastore file located for Mac OS X? I want to make a copy out of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be stored in the `/tmp` directory if you started the SDK without additional parameters.
consider starting it with the `--datastore_path=/your/path`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but i still couldn't find it from the "tmp" folder.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding --datastore_path=/your/path into the Extra Flags column, now I manage to get the datastore from the path I define.

Thanks!